# CHAT Message bubble and its autoresizing in OS X ,Xcode 6.4

Tags: macos, chat

I am developing chat application where i am not able to make Message bubble in chat window.I have tried following things but not getting desired results:

- I am not able to get background image when used Textview
- Used custom cell in view based tableview but textfield cell is not auto resizing
- Used custom cell in view based tableview this time with textview same problem

Also, I am not able to put image of file when attachments are added.

Please guide me